# How can I export a list of coc-extensions and install it on another machine?

Tags: plugin-coc

I would like to make a file list of all my coc-extensions and afterwards install them in another vim environment.

I am not able to save the output of the vim command `:CocList extensions` to a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default directory of the coc-extension a json list saves all the extensions. I wrote a little script which will save all extensions ready to install within vim.

First of all you have to install `jq` to parse the json file. On Debian based systems e.g.

```
sudo apt install jq
```

Afterwards save this script as e.g. `install-coc-extensions.bash`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# script that creates a file `install-coc-extensions.vim`
# Use this command to install it (coc.nvim plugin required):
#        vim -c 'source install-coc-extensions.vim'

echo "let g:coc_global_extensions = " > install-coc-extensions.vim
  jq '.dependencies | keys' ~/.config/coc/extensions/package.json | 
  sed "s/\"/'/g" | sed 's/^/  \\/g' >> install-coc-extensions.vim
```

or as a one-line command type this command in your bash/zsh:

```bash
cat << EOF > install-coc-extensions.vim
let g:coc_global_extensions =
$(jq '.dependencies | keys' ~/.config/coc/extensions/package.json |
sed 's/"/'"'"'/g;s/^/  \\/g')
EOF
```

Don't forget to make this script executable

```
chmod +x install-coc-extensions.bash
./install-coc-extensions.bash
```

This will create a vim file `install-coc-extensions.vim`

To install the extensions all you have to do is to run the following command  (coc.nvim plugin has to be installed)

```bash
vim -c 'source install-coc-extensions.vim'
```

or use it as session file:

```bash
vim -S install-coc-extensions.vim
```

Comment: or `vim -S install-coc-extensions.vim`. The script could be written as `{ echo 'let …'; jq … | sed -e s/\"/\'/g -e 's/^/  \\/g'; } > install-coc-extensions.vim`

Comment: That's a nice idea ! Didn't know that. Thanks for the hint.